# Removing rows in a 2D array that have the same value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a quick way to remove duplicate values present in a 2D array on a first come first serve basis. I know a way to remove the rows if they are identical, but not if only one of the values is present.

```
a = array([[0, 1],
           [3, 4],
           [3, 5],
           [2, 5],
           [1, 2]])
```

As 3 is present in a[1] and a[2] I would like to delete any future occurrence of a value. Similarly with 2 in a[3] and a[4] So the output would be:

```
a = array([[0, 1],
           [3, 4],
           [2, 5]])
```

As can be seen, there is overlap with the value 5. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to pure Python solutions?

Comment: yes,any solution would be viable. Thankfully I'm dealing with a maximum of 20/30 rows. Optimization shouldn't be much of an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure-Python way will be to use set with a list-comprehension:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> np.array([x for x in a if seen.isdisjoint(x) and not seen.update(x)])
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

The one-liner simply abuses the fact that [`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) returns `None`, so when [`seen.isdisjoint(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) is `True` we can update the `seen` set using `not seen.update(x)`.

We can also write the above code as:

```
seen = set()
out = []
for item in a:
    # if none of items in current sub-array are present in seen set
    # then add current sub-array to our list. Plus update the seen
    # set with the items from current sub-array
    if seen.isdisjoint(item):
        out.append(item)
        seen.update(item)
...         
>>> out
[array([0, 1]), array([3, 4]), array([2, 5])]
>>> np.array(out)
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

Comment: As a Python novice id love to see a sentence about how set operations and NumPy arrays work together. Maybe I don't understand sets too well but this seems like voodoo to me

Comment: This method works really well, thank you. Its also very quick, which helps. I'm a novice at python myself. My first instinct was a set of loops and if statements. But this is elegant.

Comment: @ArcAngel I've added a simpler version of the one-liner with explanation in comments.