# list comprehension with tuple comparision

Tags: python

input: `[("abc", 1, "def"), ("abc", 1, "ghi"), ("bc", 2, "a"), ("bc", 2, "b"), ("bc", 3, "a")]`

expected output: `[("abc", 1, "def"), ("bc", 2, "a"), ("bc", 3, "a")]`

I was trying something like:-
`field_list = [field for i, field in enumerate(field_list) for cmp_field in field_list[i+1:] if]`.....don't know how `if` would suit here?

I wanted to achieve this using list comprehension. Logic for getting output -- remove the duplicates(tuple is treated as duplicate if item[0] and item[1] are same).

I could achieve it using traditional for loops but I would like to get this with list comprehension. Any thoughts?

Edit: ("abc", 1, "def") and ("abc", 1, "ghi") are duplicates, so I can pick the first one.

Comment: Why should `("abc", 1 ,"ghi")` not be in your output list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549345/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-list-comprehension).

Comment: I suggest you show us how you would achieve it using traditional for loops so that it becomes clear what you want to do.

Comment: because it is duplicate as per the "duplicate definition" for this question. `("abc", 1, "def") and ("abc", 1, "ghi")` are duplicate. So pick either of them or the 1st one in output list.

Comment: Use a `set()` to keep track of seen items, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28721454/846892) if you want to do this using a list comprehension.

Comment: @mkrieger1 .... same for `("bc", 2, "a"), ("bc", 2, "b")`. Since they are duplicates. I picked the 1st one. And the duplicate definition is stated in the question. Please check.

Comment: Now I see it. Sorry for not reading carefully enough.

Comment: @mkrieger1: np...but any help :)

Comment: what's the downvote for? Can anyone explain? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549408/3495539), you might try

```
inp = [("abc", 1, "def"), ("abc", 1, "ghi"), ("bc", 2, "a"), ("bc", 2, "b"), ("bc", 3, "a")]
res = []
[res.append(el) for el in inp if not [tmp for tmp in res if tmp[0] == el[0] and tmp[1] == el[1]]]
```

Although I believe regular for loops would be better for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = [(x, y, z) for j, (x, y, z) in enumerate(input) if (x, y) not in [(x2, y2) for x2, y2, _ in input[:j]]]
# output = [('abc', 1, 'def'), ('bc', 2, 'a'), ('bc', 3, 'a')]
```

However, it might be more efficient with a traditional for loop, since you would not need to build the second list at each iteration (or a set as suggested by Ashwini Chaudhary).

Answer (score 0):

I used groupby which is an intermediate step.
.

```
In [40]: l=[("abc", 1, "def"), ("abc", 1, "ghi"), ("bc", 2, "a"), ("bc", 2, "b"), ("bc", 3, "a")]

In [41]: from itertools import groupby

In [42]: groups=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(l,key=itemgetter(1))]

In [43]: groups
Out[43]: 
[[('abc', 1, 'def'), ('abc', 1, 'ghi')],
 [('bc', 2, 'a'), ('bc', 2, 'b')],
 [('bc', 3, 'a')]]

In [44]: [elem[0] for elem in groups]
Out[44]: [('abc', 1, 'def'), ('bc', 2, 'a'), ('bc', 3, 'a')]
```

Comment: That wouldn't work with [('abc', 1, 'def'), ('def', 1, 'abc')]

Comment: before grouping  we can sort the list 'l'

Comment: @Ajay: the OP says "tuple is treated as duplicate if item[0] and item[1] are same", not "only if item[1] is the same".  Simply change your key.  (PS: you could do `next(g)` instead of `list(g)[0]`.)

Comment: what would it change? for the input [('abc', 1, 'def'), ('def', 1, 'abc')], the output should be [('abc', 1, 'def'), ('def', 1, 'abc')]

Comment: @DSM Please edit the answer.I didn't get what the questionnaire want and what people are expecting